# Collision issues in matlab

Tags: matlab, collision-detection, matlab-figure, collision

I'm trying to write a program that bounces a square around the environment.

It should be changing it's velocity when it collides with the 'walls' and the central square.

I am fairly sure I am close to getting it right but there seems to be a real issue with the collision detection which I can't figure out.

Would greatly appreciate anyone having a look and giving some pointers.

```
fps = 40; 
dt = 1/fps; 

tmax = 10; 
t = 0; 
theta = 0;
dtheta = 1/20;

p = transpose([20,20,1]); 
v = transpose([50,25,1]); 

Vobj = transpose([2, -2, 1; 2,2,1; -2, 2, 1; -2, -2, 1]);
Vobj2 = transpose([60,60,1; 60,40,1; 40, 40, 1; 40, 60, 1]);

while t < tmax
    x = p + t*v;
    if x(1)<= 5 || x(1) >= 95
      v(1)=-v(1);
    elseif x(2)<= 5 || x(2) >= 95
      v(2)=-v(2);
    elseif ((40<=x(1)) && (x(1)<= 60)) && ((x(2) == 40) || (x(2) == 60))
        v(2)=-v(2);
    elseif ((40<=x(2)) && (x(2)<= 60)) && ((x(1) == 40) || (x(1) == 60))
        v(1)=-v(1);
    end
    p = x;

    % Transformations
    T = [1,0,p(1);0,1,p(2);0,0,1];
    S = [1+0.2*sin(2*t),0,0; 0,1+0.2*sin(2*t),0;0,0,1];
    R = [cos(theta),sin(theta),0 ;-sin(theta),cos(theta),0;0,0,1];
    L = R*S*T;

    % Application of Transformations
    V = L*Vobj;

    fill(V(1,:),V(2,:),'r')

    hold on
    fill(Vobj2(1,:),Vobj2(2,:),'g')
    axis([0,100,0,100])
    hold off

    shg;
    pause(0.1);

    % Updates
    t = t + dt;
    theta = theta + dtheta;
end
```

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? What should it do and what does it do instead? Please elaborate until you have a [mcve].

Comment: You are using t at line 16 instead of dtheta. you can observe the result of it in animation, box moves faster and faster. Also, with your way of detecting crashes, box can fly off a border area if dtheta or velocity is too big. Or, it can always stay in border zone if they are too small.

Comment: A few years ago one of my professors in the university suggested that this is the nicest method of collusion detection in matlab: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html

Comment: "You are using t at line 16" dtheta is just the angle of my rotation it needs to be 1 degree per second, i think your spot on though in terms of the way the detection. The velocity shouldn't get too large though it never is changed in terms of the value it only changes in terms of the direction in the x and y. Not sure what is going on to be honest.

Comment: Andreas the code is as minimal and complete as i can make it, it's complete in the sense that it does do what i want it to do other than the fact that the detection is dodgy which is the problem.

Comment: Volkan this method seems a little advanced for what i had in mind.

Comment: I've added a little video of what it should look like.

Comment: Oh I thought you used dtheta as dt when I edited my comment. It still needs to be changed as dt as @ｒｉｃｋｅｒｔ explains. You need to learn odes to use the method I suggested. Since you are integrating, doing it with ODEs would be better because it would detect the correct dt instead of your handpicked one. Also, events for detection would be more clear. It is harder but if you are going to model movements like this you will learn ODEs eventually.

Comment: Could you point me to somewhere, where i could get the basics so i can do this in terms of odes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things not entirely correct.

Your numerical integration should multiply with `dt` instead of `t`, if you are using a forward Euler method.

You are now checking for collision at the center of the moving block, but perhaps you actually want to check for collision of the corners of the block. If that's the case, you could loop over the coordinates of the corner of the block, and check them individually with the working collision detection if statement. So instead of checking once, do the check four times for the corners. Or even multiple times, if add points by interpolating the edges of the block.

The transformation of the block is incorrect. The location of `V` is not centered about the position `p`. If you try to simplify the problem, and just take the center of the block, you will see that the collision detection is in fact working.

```
fps = 40; 
dt = 1/fps; 

tmax = 10; 
t = 0; 
theta = 0;
dtheta = 1/20;

p = transpose([20,20,1]); 
v = transpose([50,25,1]); 

Vobj2 = transpose([60,60,1; 60,40,1; 40, 40, 1; 40, 60, 1]);

while t < tmax
    x = p + dt*v;
    if x(1)<= 5 || x(1) >= 95
      v(1)=-v(1);
    elseif x(2)<= 5 || x(2) >= 95
      v(2)=-v(2);
    elseif ((40<=x(1)) && (x(1)<= 60)) && ((x(2) == 40) || (x(2) == 60))
        v(2)=-v(2);
    elseif ((40<=x(2)) && (x(2)<= 60)) && ((x(1) == 40) || (x(1) == 60))
        v(1)=-v(1);
    end
    p = x;


    % plot the center of the block
    scatter(p(1),p(2))

    % plot the obstacle
    hold on
    fill(Vobj2(1,:),Vobj2(2,:),'g')
    axis([0,100,0,100])
    hold off

    shg;
    pause(0.1);

    % Updates
    t = t + dt;
    theta = theta + dtheta;
end
```

Try to fix your transformation, by just applying some angle and translation, to a point where you know where your corners should end up (for example 90 degree rotation, or translation of a known value). This way you can check if the transformation is correct. Then incorporate this again in the simulation.

Comment: I'm not integrating anything

Comment: @Dead_Ling0 Yes in fact you are, you are numerically integrating your equation of motion. See my edit

Comment: I feel like i'm so over my head and this assignment is beyond me, iI do understand what you are saying now, i guess I've never thought of it that way before because it's in a computer program.

Comment: The collision doesn't even work for the center of the block it just goes straight through the walls and i have no idea why...

Comment: Thank you very kindly will try to work on the pointers you've given me you've been a real help :)